# Java - Don't know how to call a public enum class

Tags: java

I'am a little bit new in Java ...

Here is the Java sources that I want to implement.

First I define a public enum class like that :

```
public enum Day {
SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
```

Now I create a class like that :

```
import java.time.*;

public class EnumTest {
Day day;

public EnumTest(Day day) {
    this.day = day;
}

public void tellItLikeItIs() {
    switch (day) {
        case MONDAY:
            System.out.println("Mondays are bad.");
            break;

        case FRIDAY:
            System.out.println("Fridays are better.");
            break;

        case SATURDAY: case SUNDAY:
            System.out.println("Weekends are best.");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Midweek days are so-so.");
            break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EnumTest firstDay = new EnumTest(Day.MONDAY);
    firstDay.tellItLikeItIs();
    EnumTest thirdDay = new EnumTest(Day.WEDNESDAY);
    thirdDay.tellItLikeItIs();
    EnumTest fifthDay = new EnumTest(Day.FRIDAY);
    fifthDay.tellItLikeItIs();
    EnumTest sixthDay = new EnumTest(Day.SATURDAY);
    sixthDay.tellItLikeItIs();
    EnumTest seventhDay = new EnumTest(Day.SUNDAY);
    seventhDay.tellItLikeItIs();
}
}
```

When I compile the EnumTest class' I get this error :

```
C:\java>javac EnumTest.java
EnumTest.java:4: error: class Day is public, should be declared in a file named
Day.java
public enum Day {
   ^
1 error
```

Could you help me ?
Thank you
Meir

Comment: Are these both classes in same file?

Comment: The error message says it all: class Day is public, should be declared in a file named
Day.java

Comment: As RobbyCornelissen mentions the compiler expects the Day enum in its own source file (enums are internally handled as a class) .

Comment: The problem is not where you "called" the enum, the problem is in the line where you introduced it.

Comment: BTW If you use an IDE these have auto-fixes for this sort of problem, they not only compile the code for you but help you fix the code as well.  I prefer IntelliJ CE.

Comment: @Abimaran The true is that I don't have idea what to do. Or put them in the same file (how ?) or put them in two files (here I don't know how to do that for compiling successfully). Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems fine, The error is showing up because you are saving two public classes, (Enums are also classes) under the same file.

Create two separate files and write enum in one, save it as `Day.java`. And other file with the `class EnumTest` and save it as `EnumTest.java`
Dont forget to put them under the same package. otherwise you will have to import the Enum with `import packagename.Day`

Or

The easier method, Remove the `public` from Enum

```
     enum Day {
      SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
      THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
      }
```

Now your code will compile

Answer (score 2):

Usually all `public` classes/enums/interface are defined each in a single file each (so Day.java, EnumTest.java and so on).

But you don't have to make a class/enum/interface `public` unless it's being accessed from the outside:

```
enum Day { ... }

public class EnumTest {
    Day day;
    ...
```